# remove a selected checkbox row(single and multiple) in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to remove row(single or multiple both) whose checkbox is selected in jtable through a button but it is not working properly..it is throwing exceptions.. here is the code..

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
        for (int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++) {
              Boolean checked=(Boolean)model.getValueAt(i,7);
              if (checked) {
                   model.removeRow(i);
                   i--;
              }
        }
}
```

Comment: because if i delete one row then no of rows also decrease by one.it   is for multiple rows deletion.

Comment: He wants to delete just the selected ones.  What exception is getting thrown?

Comment: not all rows but the rows whose checkbox are selected.

Comment: NullpointerException

Comment: Post the stacktrace, and tell us with line is failing. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because if combobox isn't selected you will get `null` not `false`.to avoid this you can check null or not first

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();

    for (int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++) {
          Boolean checked=(Boolean)model.getValueAt(i,7);
          if (checked!=null && checked) {
               model.removeRow(i);
               i--;
          }
    }
```

Comment: what?are u getting any error?this is working fine for me .did you change  if (checked!=null && checked) ??

Comment: Yes i have tried your option but getting exception error(error posted above)

Comment: @user3474942 it's not poosible to get null pointer exception since check null or not before delete ..(checked!=null && checked) ..try to correctly copy and paste this code

Comment: now it is now showing arrayindexoutofbound exception... Updated program... DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
        for (int i=model.getRowCount();i>0;i--)
        {Boolean checked=(Boolean)model.getValueAt(i-1,7);
            if (checked!=null && checked)
            {
          model.removeRow(i);
          
            }}

Comment: @user3474942 hey in my code getValueAt(i,7) was getValueAt(i,0).now i corrected it .

Comment: but the checkbox is on column seven

Comment: @user3474942 yes that's why i changed it to 7

Comment: so where is the solution?

Comment: solution is in updated answer.don't mix codes from all answers .try one at a time

Comment: i have tried your whole code but it is deleting only single row even if multiple rows are checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate in a descent way:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    for (int i=model.getRowCount();i<0;i--) {
          Boolean checked=(Boolean)model.getValueAt(i-1,7); // Checkbox is in 7th column?
          if (checked) {
               model.removeRow(i-1);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4
 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)

Comment: Which line fails
`Boolean checked=(Boolean)model.getValueAt(i,7);`
or
`model.removeRow(i);` ?

Comment: it is not showing on my lines of code but on the files which are built in (like at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:470)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:649)
 at views.checkleavemanager.jButton2ActionPerformed(checkleavemanager.java:252))

Comment: checkleavemanager.java:252 is the line in your code. Which is the line? Your IDE doesn't show line numbers?

Comment: yea this is the line Boolean checked=(Boolean)model.getValueAt(i,7);

Comment: It is only working when last row is not selected otherwise (showing error arrayindexoutofbound) .. and it is not deleting first row even it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        DefaultTableModel tm= (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

    for (int i=0;i<tm.getRowCount();i++) {
          Boolean checked=(Boolean)model.getValueAt(i,0);
          if (checked!=null && checked) {
               tm.removeRow(i);
               i--;
          }
    }
    }
```